# "localString1" cannot be resolved to a variable and Type mismatch errors

Tags: java, android

Please I'm still learning java/android app development and I'm having these errors in my code. Please help.

My code looks like this

```
package com.creditswitch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

      protected void onResume() {
        MyApplication.activitycontext = this;
        System.out.println("On Resume of base activity");
        if(mReceiver == null) {
            mReceiver = new ConnectionChangeReceiver();
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, localString1); //THIS LINE IS GIVING ERROR: localString1 cannot be resolved to a variable
            System.out.println("Register Receiver");
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        System.out.println("On Pause of base activity");
        if(mReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
            System.out.println("Unregister Receiver");
            mReceiver = 0x0; // THIS LINE IS GIVING ERROR: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to BroadcastReceiver
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the parameter `localString1` coming from?

Comment: Are you trying to set the mReceiver to be null? if so, just use the null keyword...

Comment: `localString1` is never declared anywhere, therefore it cannot be resolved.

Comment: You need to show the stack trace and indicate which lines are linked to the errors.

Comment: @The Thom how do i show the stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

First of all localString1 should be declared of type intentFilter because registerReceiver method accepts two params which are:
1 BraodcastReceiver
2 IntentFilter instance
You can create an intent filter as shown below:

```
 static final String MY_ACTION = "com.my.defined.MY_ACTION";
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(MY_ACTION);
```

You have to provide the same action in the tag of your androidmanifest.xml, this can be done as shown here.

```
 <receiver android:name="MyReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.my.defined.MY_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And Second thing is you have not correctly initialized the mReceiver object.Its of type broadcastReceiver, you can not instantiate it with an integer value

to initialize it you must do the following (or create an anonymous inner class on type BroadcastReceiver):

1. create a class that extends BroadcastReceiver and override its onreceive method

   public class MyBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{

   ```
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   // your code here

   }
   ```

now create an object of this class instead on broadcastReceiver which you are

```
  MyBroadcast mReceiver = new MyBroadcast();
```

prefer doing this in oncreate method of you activity.

now you can make a call to register receiver method as shown below:

```
registerReceiver(mReceiver,intentFilter);
```

Comment: Thanks Ravinder. I got it now

Comment: Thanks, your answer has really helped. My code is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Error 1

```
localString1 needs to be defined and initialized
```

Error 2

```
0x0 is a hexadecimal value, thus cant be a assigned to a variable of type BroadcastReceiver
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace this code:

```
registerReceiver(mReceiver, localString1);
```

with this:

```
static final String SOME_ACTION = "com.yourcompany.yourapp.SOME_ACTION";
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SOME_ACTION);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

As for the second error what are you trying to do?
if you want to set mReceiver to null just give:

```
mReceiver = null;
```

Comment: thanks nahtim. i got it now.